# How to forward privileged ports with Skaffold

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, skaffold

How can I make `Skaffold` forward privileged/protected/special ports which have numbers below `1024`? In my `skaffold.yaml` I added:

```yaml
portForward:
- resourceType: service
  resourceName: foo
  port: 80
  localPort: 80
```

It works fine for all unprotected ports, but in case of port `80`, `Skaffold` automatically picks another unprotected port instead of `80`.

According to the documentation `Skaffold` runs `kubectl port-forward` on each of user-defined ports, so I granted the `kubectl` binary the capability to open privileged ports with this command `sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /path/to/kubectl`.

Everything works fine when directly running `kubectl port-forward services/foo 80:80`, but when I run `skaffold dev --port-forward` it still picks another unprotected port.

I have been using `Skaffold v1.28.1` with `Minikube v1.22.0` on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by granting the capability to open privileged ports for both `skaffold` and `kubectl` binaries:

```sh
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/local/bin/kubectl;
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/local/bin/skaffold;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  We changed Skaffold's behaviour to prevent it from allocating system ports (≤ 1024), but user-defined port-forwards with explicit `localPort`s will still be honoured.

You didn't say what ports you were seeing being allocated, but I suspect they were ports 4503–4533, in which you're hitting a bug ([#6312](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/6312)).  This bug is now fixed and will be in the next release.  You can also use the "bleeding-edge" build which is built from HEAD: the [installation instructions](https://skaffold.dev/docs/install/) have details for where to fetch these pre-built binaries.

Comment: Yes, those ports start with 4503. Thank you for your answer, I was going crazy with it.

Comment: I just tried using `Skaffold  v1.33.0`, and I still have the same problem.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check the output of `lsof -P +c0 -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` which will show the current  processes that have open listening ports, and see if anything is listening to port 80. If nothing, please open an issue on https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/new and include the logs of running with `-vtrace`, which will output additional information about allocating the local port.

Comment: And note: since you're running on Ubuntu, accessing ports < 1024 requires root privileges.

Comment: Yes, it was about the root privileges. I solved the issue with granting the capability to open privileged ports for both `skaffold` and `kubectl` binaries, not only `kubectl`. Thanks for your help.